# How does C# 5.0's async-await feature differ from the TPL?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, c#-5.0, async-await

I don't see the different between C#'s (and VB's) new async features, and .NET 4.0's [Task Parallel Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-based-asynchronous-programming). Take, for example, Eric Lippert's code [from here](https://web.archive.org/web/20151017040918/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/10/29/asynchronous-programming-in-c-5-0-part-two-whence-await.aspx):

```
async void ArchiveDocuments(List<Url> urls) {
    Task archive = null;
    for(int i = 0; i < urls.Count; ++i) {
        var document = await FetchAsync(urls[i]);
        if (archive != null)
            await archive;
        archive = ArchiveAsync(document);
    }
}
```

It seems that the `await` keyword is serving two different purposes. The first occurrence (`FetchAsync`) seems to mean, *"If this value is used **later in the method** and its task isn't finished, wait until it completes before continuing."* The second instance (`archive`) seems to mean, *"If this task is not yet finished, wait **right now** until it completes."* If I'm wrong, please correct me.

Couldn't it just as easily be written like this?

```
void ArchiveDocuments(List<Url> urls) {
    for(int i = 0; i < urls.Count; ++i) {
        var document = FetchAsync(urls[i]);       // removed await
        if (archive != null)
            archive.Wait();                       // changed to .Wait()
        archive = ArchiveAsync(document.Result);  // added .Result
    }
}
```

I've replaced the first `await` with a `Task.Result` where the value is actually needed, and the second `await` with `Task.Wait()`, where the wait is actually occurring. The functionality is `(1)` already implemented, and `(2)` much closer semantically to what is actually happening in the code.

I do realize that an `async` method is rewritten as a state machine, similar to iterators, but I also don't see what benefits that brings. Any code that requires another thread to operate (such as downloading) will still require another thread, and any code that doesn't (such as reading from a file) could still utilize the TPL to work with only a single thread.

I'm obviously missing something huge here; can anybody help me understand this a little better?

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513432/task-parallel-library-replacement-for-backgroundworker?lq=1 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12414601/async-await-vs-backgroundworker?lq=1

Comment: See this link which has neat examples: http://richnewman.wordpress.com/2012/12/03/tutorial-asynchronous-programming-async-and-await-for-beginners/

Answer (score 71, accepted):

I think the misunderstanding arises here:

> It seems that the await keyword is serving two different purposes. The first occurrence (FetchAsync) seems to mean, "If this value is used later in the method and its task isn't finished, wait until it completes before continuing." The second instance (archive) seems to mean, "If this task is not yet finished, wait right now until it completes." If I'm wrong, please correct me.

This is actually completely incorrect.  Both of these have the same meaning.

In your first case:

```
var document = await FetchAsync(urls[i]);
```

What happens here, is that the runtime says "Start calling FetchAsync, then return the current execution point to the thread calling this method."  There is no "waiting" here - instead, execution returns to the calling synchronization context, and things keep churning.  At some point in the future, FetchAsync's Task will complete, and at that point, this code will resume on the calling thread's synchronization context, and the next statement (assigning the document variable) will occur.

Execution will then continue until the second await call - at which time, the same thing will happen - if the `Task<T>`  (archive) isn't complete, execution will be released to the calling context - otherwise, the archive will be set.

In the second case, things are very different - here, you're explicitly blocking, which means that the calling synchronization context will never get a chance to execute any code until your entire method completes.  Granted, there is still asynchrony, but the asynchrony is completely contained within this block of code - no code outside of this pasted code will happen on this thread until all of your code completes.

Answer (score 26):

Anders boiled it down to a very succinct answer in the Channel 9 Live interview he did. I highly recommend it

The new Async and await keywords allow you to **orchestrate concurrency** in your applications. They don't actually introduce any concurrency in to your application.

TPL and more specifically Task is ***one way*** you can use to actually perform operations concurrently. The new async and await keyword allow you to **compose** these concurrent operations in a "synchronous" or "linear" fashion.

So you can still write a linear flow of control in your programs while the actual computing may or may not happen concurrently. When computation does happen concurrently, await and async allow you to **compose** these operations.

Comment: This doesn't actually *say* anything, does it? Let me rephrase: How does this answer the question posed?

Comment: The question is "How does C# 5.0's async-await feature differ from the TPL?" My answer is appropriate for that question IMO

Answer (score 25):

There is a huge difference:

`Wait()` blocks, `await` does not block. If you run the async version of `ArchiveDocuments()`  on your GUI thread, the GUI will stay responsive while the fetching and archiving operations are running.
If you use the TPL version with `Wait()`, your GUI will be blocked.

Note that `async` manages to do this without introducing any threads - at the point of the `await`, control is simply returned to the message loop. Once the task being waited for has completed, the remainder of the method (continuation) is enqueued on the message loop and the GUI thread will continue running `ArchiveDocuments` where it left off.

Answer (score 6):

The ability to turn the program flow of control into a state machine is what makes these new keywords intresting. Think of it as **yielding control**, rather than values.

Check out [this Channel 9 video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/Charles/Anders-Hejlsberg-Introducing-Async) of Anders talking about the new feature.

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is that the signature of `ArchiveDocuments` is misleading.  It has an explicit return of `void` but really the return is `Task`.   To me void implies synchronous as there is no way to "wait" for it to finish.  Consider the alternate signature of the function.

```
async Task ArchiveDocuments(List<Url> urls) { 
  ...
}
```

To me when it's written this way the difference is much more obvious.  The `ArchiveDocuments` function is not one that completes synchronously but will finish later.

Comment: This code would make a lot more sense if "archive" were a member or static variable, and not defined within the method...  That being said, void returning asynchronous functions are perfectly valid and acceptable, and have a "fire and forget" meaning, as per the spec documentation.

Comment: Are you saying that the call to `ArchiveDocuments()` would look like `Task task = ArchiveDocuments(List<Url> urls);`?  That doesn't seem right... and if I understand correctly, the caller isn't really waiting at all.  In fact, if it cares about the outcome of `ArchiveDocuments()`, the whole scenario falls apart and doesn't work.

Comment: @Reed, I agree they are indeed valid and correct.  I just find it very misleading and a bit presumpstious as maybe I don't want to forget ;)

Comment: @James, I'm saying that I think the difference makes a bit more senes if you consider that `Task` is also a valid return.

Answer (score 1):

The await keyword does not introduce concurrency.  It is like the yield keyword, it tells the compiler to restructure your code into lambda controlled by a state machine.

To see what await code would look like without 'await' see this excellent link: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsappdev/archive/2012/04/24/diving-deep-with-winrt-and-await.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The call to `FetchAsync()` will still block until it completes (unless a statement within calls `await`?)  The key is that control is returned to the caller (because the `ArchiveDocuments` method itself is declared as `async`).  So the caller can happily continue processing UI logic, respond to events, etc.

When `FetchAsync()` completes, it interrupts the caller to finish the loop.  It hits `ArchiveAsync()` and blocks, but `ArchiveAsync()` probably just creates a new task, starts it, and returns the task.  This allows the second loop to begin, while the task is processing.

The second loop hits `FetchAsync()` and blocks, returning control to the caller.  When `FetchAsync()` completes, it again interrupts the caller to continue processing.  It then hits `await archive`, which returns control to the caller until the `Task` created in loop 1 completes.  Once that task is complete, the caller is again interrupted, and the second loop calls `ArchiveAsync()`, which gets a started task and begins loop 3, repeat *ad nauseum*.

The key is returning control to the caller while the heavy lifters are executing.

Comment: Note that "the heavy lifters" might not be executing. They might not be in parallel at all. They might be units of work that are to be scheduled on this thread whenever this thread goes idle, for example. I'm seeing a *lot* of conflation of asynchrony with parallelism and I am eager to disabuse people of that notion; asynchrony is often about *not* producing more worker threads. The key is actually return of control to the caller *after* "the heavy lifters" have done *something* to ensure that their task completes at some time in the future.

Comment: Understand what you're saying, and agree the `await` ed method need not launch or schedule anything at all.  What prompted me to make that statement was the `archive.Wait()`.  In this example, the code is definitely written to wait for a thread to do something immediately and complete.  My statement was meant in the context of this example, only.

Comment: @JamesKing, regarding "_...need not launch or schedule anything at all_": it will _eventually_ schedule or launch s/t, right?