# Calling an async method with c#5.0

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, async-await, c#-5.0, synchronizationcontext

I do some tests with the new asynchronous pattern of C# 5.0 (async/await) I have a problem with understanding how the asynchronous methods are called.

Considering this code :

```
private async Task<string> DownloadAsync()
    {
        progress.ProgressChanged += (s, e) =>
            {
                progressBar1.Value = e.value;
            };

            return await DownloadSomething(myurl, progress);

    }

private async void CallDownloadAsync()
    {
        string text = await DownloadAsync();
        progressBar1.Value = 0;
        label1.Text = "Done!";
    }

private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CallDownloadAsync();
    }
```

So, this code works very well. When I clic the "button4" a downloading task begins and my ProgressBar  is updated correctly.

But, I'd like to compact my code a little bit more by removing CallDownloadAsync() method like this :

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new Action(async () =>
        {
            string result = await Task.Run<string>(() => DownloadAsync());
        }).Invoke();
        label1.Text = "Running...";
    }
```

So here, I want to directly initiate an action which calls the DownloadAsync method but when I hit my Button4 I have a **Cross-thread operation not valid** on the progressBar. So I do not understand what is the main difference between the Action() and the call of my CallDownloadAsync() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that in former case you call `CallDownloadAsync()` from UI thread (context).

In the latter case, `DownloadAsync()` is called from the initiated Task which is generally executed in a different thread created by TPL (Task Parallel Library) out of UI thread or threads created from it.

In WPF, UI components can be accessed only by a dedicated UI thread or (its children) threads created from under it (i.e with the same UI context).

Answer (score 4):

You may find my [`async`/`await` intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) helpful. In particular, an `async` method does not run on a background thread; `Task.Run` is used to run something on a background thread, hence the difference in your code.

In general, you should avoid `async void`, unless you're writing an `async` event handler. Like this:

```
private async void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = "Running...";
    string result = await DownloadAsync();
    progressBar1.Value = 0;
    label1.Text = "Done!";
}
```