# C# - How to work with background worker with custom code -Run,Pause,Stop?

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I am working with Background Worker but neither i am able to synchronize my progress bar nor able to stop or abort the process.

in my dowork function

```
void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    if(bw.CancellationPending==true)
    {
        e.cancel=true;
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        e.Result = abc();
    }
}
int abc()
{
    //my work
    Count++;
    return count;
}

void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if(bw.CancellationPending==true)
    {
        button17.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        label1.Content = "Aborted";
    }
    button17.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    label1.Content = "Completed";
}
private void Cancel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if(bw.IsBusy)
    {
        bw.CancelAsync();
    }
}
```

Now i want to know how could i Synchronize my Progress Bar and how to exit from the process?

Answer (score 1):

Have you set the [BackgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.workerreportsprogress.aspx) && [BackgroundWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.workersupportscancellation.aspx) properties on your instance to be `true`?

e.g.

```
var myBackgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
myBackgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
myBackgroundWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
//the rest of the init
```

If you want to report progress, you need to call the [BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ka89zff4.aspx) method from inside your `DoWork`.

Comment: i am using the same properties but still it is not able to abort the process. and for `BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress()` what parameters do i need to pass?

Comment: @neelb2 I linked to the MSDN page for that method and you have access to the intellisense. I think you can work out what the parameters are.

Answer (score 0):

This is a rubbish and trivial answer but give the Task Parallel library a whirl.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537608.aspx

This library encapsulates threads as discrete Task objects. It supports cancellation.

Be warned that in a worker thread, pause and cancellation operation have to be supported by the worker code itself, by polling pause/cancel flags and tokens. You cannot safely achieve these operations with threads alone.

*It is a nicer pattern to work with*

As for your question, 2 flags are required to support your operations. You will be need to check them at intervals during the worker code.

```
bool pause = false;
bool cancel = false;
void DoWork()
{
    try
    {
        ...
        //periodically check the flags
        if(cancel) return;
        while(paused){}; //spin on pause
        ...
    }
    finally
    {
        //cleanup operation
    }
}
```

Alastair Pitts' answer illustrates how background worker supports these features.
So does MSDN ;) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

Comment: I have gone through this link it is also not helping me in correct manner. do you have any Straight forward solution?

Comment: I'll be honest, the other answers are better but for completeness I wanted to give you information about the Task pattern as it is more flexible than the Async Event Pattern that background worker implements. I also wanted to highlight for you the actual process that you should be taking to implement cancellation and pausing as removed from the background worker - I found the event focus confusing when i was learning it.

Answer (score 0):

(You might want to check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12414601/async-await-vs-backgroundworker) other SO question/answer for details about the new `async` facility! It greatly improves the quality of life of developing this kind of operations!)

[BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) is event-based, basic usage is the following (the link provides many useful additional details):

```
var worker = new BackgroundWorker();

// The following two props must be true:
// #1: The worker will be enabled to signal its progress
worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
// #2: The worker will accept cancellation
worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;

// Now the events:

worker.DoWork += (s,e) => 
{         
    int i = 0; // This goes from 0 to 100
    // Do code, update 'i'
    worker.ReportProgress(i); 

    worker.CancelAsync();     //... to cancel the worker if needed

    // WARNING: This code *cannot* interact with the UI because
    // it's running in a different thread
};

worker.ProgressChanged += (s,e)=> 
{ 
// This is executed when you call ReportProgress() from DoWork() handler
// IMPORTANT: All UI interaction **must** happen here    

// e.ProgressPercentage gives you the value of the parameter you passed to
// ReportProgress() (this mechanism is a perfect fit for a progress bar!)
};

worker.RunWorkerCompleted+= (s,e) => 
{
    // code here runs when DoWork() is done, is canceled or throws.
    // To check what happened, the link provides this sample code:
    if (e.Cancelled == true)
    {
        // Cancelled!
    }
    else if (e.Error != null)
    {
        // Exception !
    }
    else
    {
        // Work completed!
    }
};

worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

It's important to know that (extracted from the link above):

> You must be careful not to manipulate any user-interface objects in your DoWork event handler. Instead, communicate to the user interface through the ProgressChanged and RunWorkerCompleted events.

**UPDATE** Lambdas here are used to keep code compact. You can obviously use "normal" handlers or whatever other method of attaching code to events you like/want/need.

Comment: Using lambda expressions as event handlers is very poor practice - anonymous delegates cannot be removed from the invocation list. Could you update your answer to explain why it is OK in this scenario? Otherwise, the answer is great.