# Start C# function as background process

Tags: c#, .net

I want to start the program without suspend. For example

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    test();
}

protected void test()
{            
    label1.Text = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        label1.Text += i;
        Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
}
```

When I run this program the form suspend while cycle the end.
How to make so that to run function `test()` without suspend the form, for example to run as background?

Comment: Have a look on `backgroundworker` that is what you need.

Comment: You can use class BackgroudWorker or async/await

Comment: @Manta https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12414601/async-await-vs-backgroundworker

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Asynchronous programming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/), so make your method `async` like this:

```
protected async Task test()
{
    label1.Text = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        label1.Text += i;
        await Task.Delay(500);
    }
}
```

And it would be better to use it, all the way down:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await test();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the async await method (I also replaced `Thread.Sleep` with `Task.Delay`):

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    await test();
}

protected async Task test()
{            
    label1.Text = "";
    for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        label1.Text += i;
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500)); //Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
}
```

If you are doing a lot of CPU work, you should do something like: `await Task.Run(() => ...`

You may find this [async/await](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) intro helpful.