# How to change label.text use Task.Run()

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

No work `await Task.Run()`:

```
private async void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Run(() => {
        monitor_r(label1);
    });
}

protected async Task monitor_r(Label L1)
{
    MessageBox.Show(L1.Name);
    L1.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
    L1.Text = "test";
}
```

These commands

```
MessageBox.Show(L1.Name);
```

and

```
L1.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
```

*works fine* but

```
L1.Text = "test";
```

*does not work*.

Can you help, why do not change a `Label Text`?

Comment: Why is `monitor_r` async?  You don't await anything so it could just be `void`.

Comment: `does not work.` @Mike it may be helpful for you to give a bit more detail as to what `does not work` means. Was an exception thrown, for example (and if so, which one)?

Answer (score 5):

Try [Control.Invoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.invoke?view=netframework-4.7.2): we should run Winform UI in the *main thread* only

```
protected async Task monitor_r(Label L1)
{
    Action action = () => 
    {
        MessageBox.Show(L1.Name);

        L1.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
        L1.Text = "test";
    };

    if (L1.InvokeRequired)
        L1.Invoke(action); // When in different thread
    else 
        action();          // When in the main thread
}
```

Comment: Thank you, work fine. Only need to put ; after Action action = () => 
    {
        MessageBox.Show(L1.Name);

        L1.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
        L1.Text = "test";
    };

Comment: @Mike: I see, I'm sorry for the typo.

Comment: Thanks a million for help

Answer (score 1):

If you're on debug mode, take a look at the output window. It should shows exception message something like this:

> System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Windows.Forms.dll.

That because `label1` accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on. And it will causing invalid cross-thread operation.

You can solve this by using `Control.Invoke` as Dmitry Bychenko already mentioned. Here is simple extension to make thread-safe calls to Winforms Control.

```
public static void TryInvoke(this Control control, Action<Control> action)
{
      if (control.InvokeRequired) control.Invoke(new Action(() => action(control)));
      else action(control);
}
```

**Sample usage**

```
label1.TryInvoke(x => x.Text = "test"); 
label1.TryInvoke(x => x.ForeColor = Color.Blue);
```

**Or**

```
this.TryInvoke(x =>
{
     label1.Text = "test";
     label1.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
});
```

Secondly, since you don't await anything at `monitor_r`, i'd recommend to use `void` instead of `async Task`.

Even if you're await something at `monitor_r` you don't need

```
await Task.Run(() => {
        monitor_r(label1);
    });
```

..because `monitor_r` itself is a task. So just call `await monitor_r(label1);`

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to have a separate thread, you can try this using BackgroundWorker. You can implement the ReportProgress if you have a loop.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker()
        {
            WorkerReportsProgress = true,
            WorkerSupportsCancellation = true
        };
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += Worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
        worker.RunWorkerAsync();                
    }

    private void Worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(label1.Name);
        label1.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
        label1.Text = "test";
    }
```

Comment: Please, let `BackgroundWorker` *rest in peace*: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12414601/async-await-vs-backgroundworker

Comment: **Since both work, it comes down to personal preference as to which you use when. What is quicker for you? What is easier for you to understand?** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12414601/async-await-vs-backgroundworker

Comment: TPL (Task Process Library) has been designed in order to substitute `BackgroundWorker` and other obsolete solutions. Yes, `BackgroundWorker` works (in some simple cases); however, it brings problems (what if have to I start `BackgroundWorker` from `BackgroundWorker` in my routine version `5.1`?) https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/05/taskrun-vs-backgroundworker-intro.html

Comment: Thank you all for your help