# C# : Show progress bar change in custom message box

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar, backgroundworker

I have a 2 forms, **MainForm** and **ProgressForm**.

**#1 MainForm.cs has a button, which when clicked starts my backgroundWorker1.**

```
 ProgressForm pg = new ProgressForm(); 

 private void StarBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           
           pg.Show();
           
            if(!backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)
            {
                backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
        }

 private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
          //time consuming tasks...
        }
```

**#2 ProgressForm is where I have added a progress bar and a label**.

```
namespace MainApp
{
    public partial class ProgressForm : Form
    {
        public ProgressForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    }
}
```

I need to show the progress of my background process in `MainForm` to `progressBar1` in `ProgressForm` (as below)

```
 private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
           //something like..
           //this.progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
           //in ProgressForm...
            
        }
```

and show a completed in label and close the form.

```
private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
           //label.Text = "Completed"
          // Close the ProgressForm...
            
        }
```

How can I access the elements in ProgressFrom from backgroundworker in MainForm and make the progress update.

Comment: As a side note the `BackgroundWorker` class is [technologically obsolete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12414601/async-await-vs-backgroundworker/64620920#64620920). A better way of offloading work to a background thread is the `Task.Run` method, combined with async/await.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your background worker events are in the MainForm? If so then add public properties to your ProgressForm and set the label and / or progress bar accordingly to the provided values.

ProgressForm

```
public int Progress {
set {
    progressBar1.Value = value;
  }
}
public string LabelText{
set {
   label.Text = value;
  }
}
```

MainForm

```
pg.Progress = e.ProgressPercentage;
```

Comment: Tried this but progress bar is not updating. Even tried this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { inside set command. Still not updating

Comment: I use the same approach in different projects. So far it has always worked. Where do you set the two properties? In which event?

Comment: I used the 'set' property on ProgressForm and in MainForm, I called pg.Progress = e.ProgressPercentage; inside backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged event. Any initilization of progressbar is required?

Comment: Is your ProgressChanged event called? Did you set 
  backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;

Comment: backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true is set already. But do I need to call  ProgressChanged ?I thought it responded like backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted which give response once RunWorkerAsync is completed.

Comment: You have to call ProgressChanged yourself. The BackgroundWorker doesn't know how much of your job is already done.

Comment: I don't have a 'for loop' to report progress of each step. I have 2 functions api.initilize(); and api.start() ,each taking 3-4 secs to finish execution. How can I report the progress then? hardcoding  backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(50) on completion of api.initilize(); and again  backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(50) on completion of api.start()