# Can't loop e.Result from RunWorkerCompleted Event

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

```
Dictionary<string, int> myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();
```

is created inside background event _DoWork and returned like so:

```
e.Result = myDictionary;
```

now inside my _RunWorkerCompleted event I want to loop though result like so:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> kvp in e.Result)
{
 ...
}
```

but I keep getting

> Error CS1579  foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'object' because 'object' does not contain a public instance or extension definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Why is that?
I can loop it inside DoWork event but not when I pass it to RunWorkerCompleted

Comment: Why are you using the obsolete BackgroundWorker class? Everything it does is actually easier to do with `Task.Run`, `async/await` and `IProgress`. On the other hand, simple things like making two consecutive async calls are extremely complicated to do with BGW

Comment: Can you provide a minimally reproducible example?

Comment: Because `Result` is of type `object`, you need to cast it to `Dictionary<string, int>` `foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> kvp in (Dictionary<string, int>) e.Result)`

Comment: @Evk thank you for the explanation that fixes it.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos well it works I spent a lot of time on it and I didn't know I could make separate thread in an easier way

Comment: @Orangutan if it worked well you wouldn't have to deal with `object` and get the compilation error you got. You need to cast the result but that's not obvious. On the other hand, `KeyValuePair<string, int> result=await Task.Run(()=>myFunction()); foreach(KeyValuePair<string, int> kvp in result){...}` simply works

Comment: @Orangutan you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12414601/async-await-vs-backgroundworker/64620920#64620920) an example of how to replace a `BackgroundWorker` with `Task.Run` & async/await.

Comment: @Orangutan casting from object may not seem so bad when dealing with classes. With value types like structs, integers, etc casting *wraps* them in an `object` that needs to be garbage collected.