# Background worker Is busy error and I want to implement in progress bar

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, backgroundworker, cross-thread

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //progress bar
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    progressBar1.Value = 1;
    progressBar1.Minimum = 1;
    progressBar1.Maximum = 10;
    label3.Text = "backgroundworker Task completed";

    Thread.Sleep(100);
    Application.DoEvents();
    // end of bgw
}
```

I am getting error on the `Backgroundworker1.RunworkerAsync()` where it shows an error of `Backgroundworker` is busy and try to use it aftertime.
Is there any other method to solve. I thank in advance.

Comment: Your code makes little sense as it is. I suggest that you read [this](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?542316-Using-the-BackgroundWorker-Component) to learn how to use a `BackgroundWorker` properly.

Comment: Just had a closer look at that old thread of mine and there's probably not as much information there as I thought. You are displaying a message in a `Label` as though you think the work is finished at that point, yet you are setting the initial state of the `ProgressBar` immediately beforehand. That's nonsense. Set up the initial state first, call `RunWorkerAsync`, do the work in the `DoWork` event handler, then update the UI after the work in the `RunWorkerCompleted` event handler.

Comment: Never ever ever ever call `Application.DoEvents()`. It is evil incarnate and will cause you more grief than relief.

Comment: I would consider using a Task instead of a background worker. Stephen Cleary has a [article about using progress reporting from tasks](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/reporting-progress-from-async-tasks.html) that might be useful.

Comment: The `BackgroundWorker` class is old and awkward. You can take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12414601/async-await-vs-backgroundworker/64620920#64620920 "Async/await vs BackgroundWorker") for an alternative (`Task.Run` + `await` + `IProgress<T>`).

Answer (score 1):

When you call `RunWorkerAsync`, the `IsBusy` property will return `True`. The `BackgroundWorker` will raise its `DoWork` event and you do your background work in that event handler. Once that event handler completes, it will raise its `RunWorkerCompleted` event and you can optionally handle that event to update the UI after the background work. Once the event handlers for both events complete, the `IsBusy` property will return `False`. The whole point of that property is to tell you that the `BackgroundWorker` is already busy so you shouldn't call `RunWorkerAsync`. The solution to your problem is not call `RunWorkerAsync` until `IsBusy` is `False` again, e.g.

```cs
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)
    {
        return;
    }

    // Setup ProgressBar and whatever else here first.

    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```