# Understanding async and await

Tags: c#, async-await, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to learn the details of MVC5 and I came across something that baffles me.  In the accountController that comes by default with an MVC5 project with Individual Auth there is this line of code in the async Login and Register methods

```
var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
```

I read here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx that this is a normal practice, but I do not understand why you would ever use an asynchronous method and await in the same line.  Wouldn't it make more sense to just use the .Create method that takes the same parameters here?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057359/new-c-sharp-await-feature

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4054263/how-does-c-sharp-5-0s-async-await-feature-differ-from-the-tpl?rq=1

Comment: What I am getting out of the second post is that it will spin up a new thread to do the .CreateAsync instead of using the current one.  Is that it?  Is there any real value in that?

Comment: There is no new thread involved. It simply make better use of the current thread. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19087513/what-is-the-advantage-of-using-async-with-mvc5

Comment: Thank you that explained it perfectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between `SomeMethod()` and `await SomeMethodAsync()` is that the latter won't block a thread while the method performs IO. Because of that, the application becomes more scalable, because it can use smaller number of threads to serve the same number of requests.

If you don't care about scalability, then it doesn't matter much which of the two options are you going to choose. But it's probably still better to use the async version, to future-proof your application, so that your application behaves well when scalability becomes an issue.

Comment: That's only valid on the presence of a synchronization context, right?

Comment: @PauloMorgado `async`-`await` works without synchronization context too. In that case, the continuations resume on the thread pool.