# C# backgroundworker started within a for loop

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I have the following code to start a background worker:

```
foreach (var item in this.lstbxItems.Items)
{
    if (!bw.IsBusy)
        bw.RunWorkerAsync(item);
}
```

Is there a way to wait for the background worker (`bw`) to finish and then send to it the next item in the list?

Comment: Which version of .net framework you use? If 4.0 or greater, throw away Backgroundworker and use `Task`.

Comment: I recommend using [TPL then](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513432/task-parallel-library-replacement-for-backgroundworker) which will make many of tasks easier. Like waiting for the operation to complete, start multiple tasks concurrently, error handling etc.

Comment: This sounds like a perfect situation for using Microsoft's Reactive Extensions (NuGet "Rx-WinForms").

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a perfect situation for using Microsoft's Reactive Extensions (NuGet "Rx-WinForms").

Your code would look something like this:

```
var query =
    from item in this.lstbxItems.Items.ToObservable()
    from result in Observable.Start(() => ProcessItem(item))
    select new { item, result };

IDisposable subscription =
    query
        .ObserveOn(this) /* marshals to UI-thread */
        .Subscribe(x =>
        {
            /* do something with each `x.item` & `x.result`
            as soon as they are asyncronously computed */
        });
```

If you needed to stop the computation before it completes naturally you can just call `subscription.Dispose()`.