# Correct usage of BackgroundWorker in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, backgroundworker

I am trying my best with mastering Threading in C# and in WPF particularly.
**Background of the problem:**
I have a MVVM application, which have a long authentication process (few seconds long). I want to keep the UI responsible (keep app window dragable and resizable, as well - showing preloader with a gif element). 
To achieve that - I have separated all the UI elements and DB retrievals. After that - I have implemented the A background worker into the Login View.

**Here is the code of the Login View:**

```
    private void ValidateLogin()
    {
        Usuario user = new Usuario();
        MainWindow mw = Window.GetWindow(this) as MainWindow;
        mw.preloaderShow();

        BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();

        bw.DoWork += (o, args) =>
        {   
            user = _viewmodel.Login(tbLogin.Text, tbPassword.Password); //TimeConsuming DataRetrieval from DB
        };
        bw.RunWorkerCompleted += (o, args) =>
        {   
            if (user != null)
            {
                if (user.Activo == 0)
                {
                    mw.preloaderHide();
                    CustomMessageBox WrongLoginMessage = new CustomMessageBox("El usuario esta inactivo.");
                    WrongLoginMessage.ShowDialog();
                }
                else
                {
                    AppSession.Instance.SetValue("currentuser", user);
                    btnProceed.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    mw.preloaderHide();
                }
            }
        };

        bw.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
```

**Problem:**
Obviously I am falling into a deadlock, on the bw.DoWork, because "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.".

**Questions:**
**1.** Since I am not updating any UI in the bw.DoWork() (lets consider this as a fact at this moment), - why is the Background worker busy? I mean - as I understood, that the whole conception was introduced to run processes in a separated Thread with as less pain as possible?
**2.** How to retrieve the User from DB while keeping the UI responsive? Maybe BackgroundWorker is not the best concept for achieving this goal (Task / TaskFactory)?

Will be very appreciated with helping me on this one.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I can simply gues about the reason of downvote.

Comment: You really should avoid such old and heavy object as `BackgroundWorker` in WPF solution

Comment: @VMAtm I can understand what you trying to say, but it would be way more useful if you would say what solution do you recommend (Task?).

Comment: The question received several downvotes already. It may be not the best solution - yes. But the question is more than reasonable, described pretty solid and raised pretty often. I don`t really care about the rep points, but it decreases the chances to help others.

Comment: I suggest `async` event handler with it's ability to execute code **after** long operation on the UI

Comment: @VMAtm I execute event async in BackgroundWorker.DoWork and execute UI operations BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted **after** long calculation. If using `async` I will have to handle dedicated Thread manualy, which (in this particular situation) would not give me any cheese. Which difference am I missing (seriously)?

Comment: Why do you will need to handle the dedicated thread? `async` operations are done in Thread pool, you do not control the threads. And `BackgroundWorker` is heavy object, you should test both approaches to see the difference in speed.

Comment: @VMAtm that is a reasonable explaination. Thank you.

Comment: http://stephencleary.com/ - good place to start with `async` reading. Good luck with your projects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple thumb rule is you **cannot access UI element from background thread**. You are accessing textbox and password control in DoWork which results in an exception.

Fetch user name and password on UI thread and you are good.

```
string userName = tbLogin.Text;
string password = tbPassword.Password;
bw.DoWork += (o, args) =>
{   
   user = _viewmodel.Login(userName, password); 
};
```

Comment: My friend - that is the solution. What I`ve learned - you cant not just Update UI, but interact with the UI from the BackgrounWorker. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
private async void ValidateLogin()
{
    MainWindow mw = Window.GetWindow(this) as MainWindow;
    mw.preloaderShow();

    Task<Usuario> taskLogin = Login(tbLogin.Text, tbPassword.Password);
    await taskLogin;

    Usuario user = taskLogin.Result;

    if (user != null)
    {
        if (user.Activo == 0)
        {
            mw.preloaderHide();
            CustomMessageBox WrongLoginMessage = new CustomMessageBox("El usuario esta inactivo.");
            WrongLoginMessage.ShowDialog();
        }
        else
        {
            AppSession.Instance.SetValue("currentuser", user);
            btnProceed.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            mw.preloaderHide();
        }
    }
}

public Task<Usuario> Login(string loginText, string password)
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        return new Usuario();
    });
}
```

Use Task instead of backgroundworker.

Comment: What would be the significant benefit of using Task instead? (I am serious - does it work faster / lighter)

Comment: More information [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513432/task-parallel-library-replacement-for-backgroundworker).

Comment: I don't like the way you have to write the backgroundworker (Syntax). The code looks much cleaner when you use a Task. There aren't big antvantages using task. It uses newer API and handels asynchron procedures better. If its faster or not i don't know.